# WP7 - Implementing a tree of comments. ListBox, Tree controls, etc?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to implement a screen to display a tree of comments in WP7. Each comment can have children comments and so on. Each child comment will be visually distinct from its parent via indenting

ie:

```
"comment text"
    "Some child comment text"
    "Some child comment text"
        "some child comment text"
"comment text"
    "Some child comment text"
```

What would be the best way to go about implementing this? I'd like to keep the implementation as simple as possible so initially I was thinking I could use a single ListBox and programmatically set the Padding/Margin of each comment/ListItem, depending on its depth in the tree. But I can't seem to get it working. Any examples, suggestions, recommendations, etc?

Edit: Doing some additional reading, it seems like a DataTrigger would have been perfect for this sort of thing http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113152/Applying-Data-Templates-Dynamically-by-Type-in-WP7 ...But WP7 doesn't support triggers.

One other idea I had was to make the Margin/Padding a Property of the Comment class, and then databind to that...this should work, but I'm contaminating my Comment class with display information. Any ideas on how I could databind the Margin/Padding value but somehow not mix model & view codes?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to roll your own, either from scratch, or by assembling something out of existing controls. ListBox looks like a good bet for this purpose.

Take a peek at [this MSDN thread (web archive - thread now moved/deleted)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120513015030/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/db91d4b2-5d20-456e-8a4a-b000e81f4ca3), it has several suggestions about simulating a TreeView using a ListBox, and a claim (which I have not verified) that you can use `System.Windows.Controls.TreeView` in WP7 (with the caveat that you also need `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit`).

The marked answer, written by Shaun Taulbee:

> Tree view behaviour in a listbox could be mimiced with a bit of smarts in the collection handling. Features your classes would need to support that come to mind are
>
> - a collection whose elements supports retrieving child collections
> - similarly to be able to detect if an element has child collections
> - in the data template for the listbox show one element of the stackpanel for expansion state based on presence of children and whether or not expanded
> - in the data template for the listbox show one element of the stackpanel for indent which reflects the depth of the child - to accomplish this best you should have a collection that represents a flat version of your tree data to bind to - then when you insert items you can make the indent based on the indent of the parent item that was just clicked
> - when a node is clicked in the listbox you insert the children from that node into the flat collection that the listbox is bound to
> - when the node is clicked again the children are deleted from the flat collection
>
> You could encapsulate all of this into some neat classes to provide a fairly simple reusable api I would imagine if you wanted.

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-US/280e916d-eede-48ec-a8b8-c37037104eb9/treeview-control) has a fair amount of noise, but down at the bottom there's a comment from Mark Chamberlain:

> "TreeView is not a natural fit for the phone, you can emulate Treeview
> in other ways, for example, with ListBox item templates, Pivot or with
> other List patterns.  It will depend on how many levels of the tree
> you will have.
>
> "For example, you can template your ListItem to contain a label and
> another Listbox with same item template.   Doing this you can emulate
> as many drill in levels as you need to handle, but only one branch at
> a time."
>
> "You may be able to re-template the TreeView (source is also available
> in the Silverlight Toolkit), but it isn’t a supported scenario, and
> you would need to do a decent amount of work to get it looking good on
> the phone from a design & re-templating standpoint."

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Pete. I have updated the links and added additional information.

Comment: Thanks man! It's odd since the default email app has some sort of tree view structure going on to categorise emails from the same sender.

Answer (score 0):

The following should be good starting points, both altering the ItemTemplate for a ListBox control :-

http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/

http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/10/27/windows-phone-list-box-with-images.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For WP8 you can use this one [TreeView_WP8](https://treeviewwp8.codeplex.com/)